# Best practice on UUID in url path request - JsonParseException Jackson

Tags: java, kotlin, url, jackson, uuid

Not able to use UUID in the url path on request. In my company we are creating a new REST API and have encountered an issue with how to represent our UUID PK's in the url path.

We are using Kotlin with Jackson as the serializer. Running a test with the UUID in the url path gives the exception:

```
Text: "{"message":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed\n at [Source:
(ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]"
```

We have tried configuring Jackson to allow leading zeros for number with:

```kotlin
fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()
        .enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_LEADING_ZEROS_FOR_NUMBERS.mappedFeature())
        .registerModule(KotlinModule())
```

This resolves the jsonparseexception mentioned above, but introduces a new one when re-running the test:

```
Text: "{"message":"com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: 
Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level 
values\n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 10]"
```

Our workaround as of this moment is to wrap the UUID in quotations, i.e:

```bash
endpoint/"uuid"
```

Questions:

- Is our current solution with quotations considered best practice?
- And if that is the case, is there a configuration that can handle this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Never used , but there is [UUIDDeserializer](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/UUIDDeserializer.html) , have you tried to use it ?

Comment: Thank you @dariosicily. We will look into this possibility further. Thanks for the suggestion.